ASP.NET MVC (blocked:csp) error when running in local
I am getting the (blocked:csp) error in my Chrome browser when my app.
I have the headers set up like this:
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Security-Policy",
    "default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' http://localhost:5000; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:;");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
    "default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' http://localhost:5000; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:;");

If I change the http://localhost:5000 (what is the address of my API) to a live server version, when deployed it works.
The ASP.NET MVC app not works only in the local environment, and that is essential for us.
Any ideas?
Thanks
